# Lindelöf paper on meromorphic singularities

Tags: resolution-of-singularities, meromorphic-functions

Does anyone know a digital link to the following paper, written by Ernst Lindelöf:

"Mémoire sur certaines inégalités dans la théorie des fonctions monogènes,
et sur quelques propriétés nouvelles de ces fonctions dans le voisinage d’un point singulier essentiel
(Acta Societatis Scientiarum Fennicæ, t. XXXV, no 7, 1908)."

There seems to be no link available for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It’s available at Biodiversity Library:

https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/49762#page/413/mode/1up

Comment: Francois. This is much appreciated! I've been looking in vain for it for some time.